# Rewrite rule for prepending /something to a root URL with query strings

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL as follows:
www.xyz.com/?_ARGS=/string/_includes/header/header.jsp_AF&_dynSessConf=1234567890&/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.logout=true&_D%3A/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.logout=+

I need to add /something after the root url to convert to the following form:
www.xyz.com/something/?_ARGS=/string/_includes/header/header.jsp_AF&_dynSessConf=1234567890&/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.logout=true&_D%3A/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.logout=+

I have the rewrite condition figured out where logout=true is the main keyword. But I am not sure what the rewrite rule should be.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} logout=true 
RewriteRule  [QSA,NC,NE,R=301,L]

I need your suggestion guys.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your first step in rewriting is to simply insert /something at the beginning of any URI that lacks it,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/something  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$   /something/$1  [L]
```

could be enough. From there, you can do other rewrites as needed.

Comment: Hi Phil, I am not sure that is correct. I do not want to add /something in every URL but only in the URLs where query string contains logout=true. And I also want to append the query string.

Comment: Try adding another condition: `RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  logout=true  [NC]`. The original query string should be automatically appended, since you don't give a new query string, but you can add the [QSA] flag if it makes you feel more secure (or you specify a new query string in the rewrite).